# Correct way to implement search?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to implement searching books in my meteor app.

So I have this collection called `Books`, and I need to create a logic to search books by their title.

After a full day reading through the Meteor docs, I implemented the searching logic, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it.

Here's what I did:

#### Server

```
Meteor.publish('Books', constraints => {
    // Validate constraints, and generate search query

    return Books.find(<search query>);
});
```

#### Client (React component)

```
Meteor.subscribe('Books', { <search constraints> }, {
        onReady: function () { this.setState({ books: Books.find().fetch() }) }.bind(this)
 });
```

But I found that `Books.find().fetch()` in the `onReady` function returned the previous set of collections **appended** by the search results (removing duplicates, however), instead of returning just the search results.

This is really unintuitive, as the previous set of collections is not cleared out before populating the results of the new subscribe/publish cycle.

So, I fixed this by doing executing the search query again at the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('Books', { <search constraints> }, {
        onReady: function () { this.setState({ books: Books.find(<search query>).fetch() }) }.bind(this)
 });
```

But that really doesn't feel right, as I'm executing the search query twice, at both the server and client.

Is it mandatory to make an additional query at the client's end?

If yes, then am I supposed to remove the search logic from the server?

If yes, then what if not all `Books` are present in the client's *Minimongo*, while searching at the client's end (say, due to pagination)?

Is there a more appropriate or **"standard"** way to implement such an action, or am I misinterpreting the way Meteor's `publish/subscribe` must be used?

Answer (score 0):

Use a session to store the search constraints and subscribe the books in tracker.autorun which subscribe the books on change of session.

```
Templae.yourTemplateName.onCreated(function(){
       var self = this;
       self.autorun(function(){
          var searchQuery =Session.get("searchqery"); 
          self.subscribe( 'Books',searchQuery)
       })
    })
```

Comment: I wrote this code in my React component's constructor, but I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: self.autorun is not a function`. **PS:** I'm using a React component instead of a Meteor template. Can you write the code which can be used in a React component too?

Comment: I don't know about react component but You can use `Tracker.autorun` instead of  `self.autorun`